# WebAuthn authenticator attestation response id and rawId

Tags: webauthn, authenticator, fido, attestations

I would like to ask a question regarding `id` and `rawId`.

When implementing webauthn, in the authenticator attestation response, I see that we have both `id` and `rawId` . Reading the spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-1/#dom-publickeycredential-rawid) , `id` is `base64url(rawId)`

```json
{
  "type": "public-key",
  "id": "AV1--2gCLXLF9_5bGWDwZn6FP_OqAWfKY74mckatWMgN65o5OW8q2k9XVbYl8kAqPtpEoBlM0opKEjwDqYRBDIYbAl058O8ZQWS-r0M0L-9ikcu3tKuMxfFnRZ9gU6tnDH6QqzYwUg",
  "rawId": "AV1--2gCLXLF9_5bGWDwZn6FP_OqAWfKY74mckatWMgN65o5OW8q2k9XVbYl8kAqPtpEoBlM0opKEjwDqYRBDIYbAl058O8ZQWS-r0M0L-9ikcu3tKuMxfFnRZ9gU6tnDH6QqzYwUg",
  "response": {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

So here is my questions:

- why we need `id`
- why in the example above, my `id` is exactly like `rawId`?

  - does it's always the same? If it does, can we get rid of `id` in the response?
- If I save the public key `id` to the database (later use that public key `id` to create the `allowCredentials` list), which one below should I follow?

  1. save `id` in the database, use `id` to create allowCredentials list
  2. save `base64url(rawId)` in the database, then use that base64 url encoded value to create `allowCredentials` list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Q1. Why we need id

The answer to *why* we have both id and rawId is because it's by design in the spec:

> id is inherited from Credential, though PublicKeyCredential overrides Credential's getter, instead returning the base64url encoding of the data contained in the object’s identifier internal slot.
>
> https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#iface-pkcredential

#### Q2. why in the example above, my id is exactly like rawId? does it's always the same? If it does, can we get rid of id in the response?

We get back raw bytes for rawId, which must be compared to the bytes encoded in id as part of the initial verification of the registration response, so technically we can't drop it.

Besides, for whatever reason, if base64url encoding is inappropriate, RP might use unencoded raw value so rawId is returned as well.

#### Q3. If I save the public key id to the database (later use that public key id to create the `allowCredentials` list), which one below should I follow?

It's up to RP implementation, as said above, for whatever reason, if base64url encoding is inappropriate, RP might use unencoded raw value and encode it to whatever format RP prefers.

I store id because it's already encoded into a format that easy to copy/paste and compare in logs when troubleshooting. Later we will use that id to create the `allowCredentials` and send it back to the authenticator. No need to do the extra work of `base64url(rawId)`, use the `id` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's likely that the ArrayBuffer containing `rawId` has been converted to base64 for serialization purposes, hence why they look identical in your example.

As for which to use, I don't think it matters as long as the value is presented in the correct encoding or structure at the point of needing it.

The library I'm using provides and expects a byte[] but I store it as base64 in the DB. This is then converted to base64 again when serialized to send the value to the client side and then converted back to an ArrayBuffer on the client side before passing to `navigator.credentials.get()`.

As for why it's like this, I suspect there was a usecase where converting `id` from a base64 string was not desirable so the PublicKeyCredential type added it's own ArrayBuffer representation of the `[[identifier]]` slot but that's just my conjecture.